# wget result from site with cookies

Tags: linux, bash, curl, wget

Trying to enter a number here in the website and get the result with WGET.
[http://]

I've tried `wget --cookies=on --save-cookies=site.txt URL` to save the sessionID/cookie,
then went on with '`wget --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=site.txt URL`', but with no luck.

Also tried monitoring the POST data sent with WireShark and tried replicating it with wget --post-data --referer etc, but also without luck.

Anyone who has an easy way of doing this? I'm all ears! :)

All help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the HTML source code of your website? It uses some Javascript and some `;jsessionid=73ABDB6`... in the URL....

Comment: Yes, Sir. I've tried sending the URL+;jsessionid=SESSION_ID_NUMBER (which is stored in the cookie). Also tried setting it with --header "Cookie: JSESSIONID=SESSION_ID_NUMBER", which is the output from WireShark when the POST data is being sent with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to send the second request to `http://202.91.22.186/dms-scw-dtac_th/page/?wicket:interface=:0:2:::0:`

With my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) it seems to work like this (do not have a valid number to test)

```
xidel "http://202.91.22.186/dms-scw-dtac_th/page/"  -f '{"post": "number=0812345678", "url": resolve-uri("?wicket:interface=:0:2:::0:")}' -e "#id5"
```

Comment: I have tried sending the second request to that URI as well, with wget. Still no success. Always get the 'page expired'-page. My guess is there are some other calculations involved as well, since the full request URI sent when watching with WireShark shows a total of 3 requests per Submit button press, where the URI, as you mention starts with wicket:interface=:0:2:::0: and ends with random=0.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.

Comment: The other requests (except the last) and the random part do not matter, as it works without for me

Comment: Thank you,  sir. It worked with xidel :) Any knowledge of how this same procedure could be done with wget?

Comment: not sure how to do it with wget; but xidel prints all get/post requests it does to stderr, so if you send the same requests with wget and the cookie option  it should work